# Why is the CSS Hover Selector illuminating text even when it is not directly hovered over the text(and how can I fix this)?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in html and css so I'm not sure if my problem has a simple solution. Basically, I want the text to change color when I hover my mouse over it so I am using the hover selector command in CSS. The problem I am running into is that the text will illuminate when the mouse is on the same row(not sure if this makes sense) and not solely when it is on the text. [Visual of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iBHW.jpg)
[I'm not sure if the margin of the flex-box has to do with any of this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKBHi.png)

I've tried to adjust the the flex-box margins but it seems to be anchored on the left side and I can't get it to work. Like I said I'm a beginner so I kinda suck at debugging b/c I'm still learning the ropes.

Edit: Forgot to add code snippets

```css
.flex-list {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;
  flex: 1 50px;
}
  
.list1:hover {
  color:  #87C1E8;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-list"> 

          <p class="list1"> Fashion</p>
          <p class="list1"> Wellness</p>
          <p class="list1"> Lifestyle</p>
          <p class="list1"> Advise </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your actual HTML+CSS.

Comment: My bad. Just added some code snippets.

Comment: Paragraphs are "block-level" elements, so they stretch across the page unless you tell them to behave differently. What are you trying to achieve here? Will these be clickable? In that case, wrap `<a>` elements around them and set the hover styles on those instead. And since this is a "list", consider using an unordered list instead. Happy to make a demo if you clarify what you want here.

Comment: Just put `width: fit-content` in the styles for `.list-one`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quickfixes:

1. You can apply `max-width: fit-content` on the `<p>`-elements. This way, the `<p>`-element will only stretch its width as far as it has content to fill it out.
2. You can apply `align-items: flex-start` on the flex-container.

Furthermore, you should remove the flexbox margin and line-height, if you want the hover effect to be accurate vertically as well. You could use `flex-gap: 50px` instead.

```css
/* ---  Max-width ---*/
.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.list1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  /*line-height: 2;
  flex: 1 50px; */
  max-width: fit-content;
}


/* ---  Flex-start ---*/
.flex-start {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex-start-list {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  /*line-height: 2;
  flex: 1 50px;*/
  flex-gap: 50px;
}


.list1:hover, .flex-start-list:hover {
  color: #87C1E8;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-list">
  <p class="list1"> Fashion</p>
  <p class="list1"> Wellness</p>
  <p class="list1"> Lifestyle</p>
  <p class="list1"> Advise </p>
</div>



<div class="flex-start">
  <p class="flex-start-list"> flex-start</p>
  <p class="flex-start-list"> flex-start</p>
  <p class="flex-start-list"> flex-start</p>
  <p class="flex-start-list"> flex-start</p>
</div>
```